# Organising duplications in MySQL

Tags: mysql, duplicates

Assuming this is my table:

```
email |  col1 |  col2
------+-------+------
a@a   |   1   |   0
a@a   |   0   |   1
b@b   |   0   |   1
c@c   |   1   |   0
```

I'm trying to update each row where email has more than one of the same entry.  In the table above a@a is listed twice with a 1 in col1 and in the next record a 1 in col2.  I'd like a single record for a@a with a 1 in both col1 and col2. and then I can remove duplications afterwards.

I should then be left with a table where only in record exists for each email and I can then filter on having 1 in col1, col2 or both.

I've tried sorting this data using group by email having col1 = 1 and col2 = 1, but that won't work (presumably it only filters on the first record found, not a combined subset of the data - makes sense).

I'm sure this is an easy one and I'm just having another one of those days, any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have max two records duplicated? And values can be only zeros and ones? How do you choose correct values?

Comment: Yes, sorry, there can only be a maximum of 2 email address to cause a duplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

would this help:

```
select email, max(col1) as col1, max(col2) as col2 from table group by email
```

Comment: That helps a lot!  Feeling a bit silly for not thinking about MAX().  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into table_new 
select email, max(col1), max(col2) 
from table_old
group by email
```